# First order non-linear ordinary equations

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I want to solve the following first order non-linear equations:

$$\tag{E} 4x^3yy'-3x^4-y^4=0.$$

My try:

I divide (E) by $y^4$, then 
$$(E) \Leftrightarrow 4x^3\frac{y'}{y^3}-\frac{3x^4}{y^4}=1,$$
I assumed that $Y=y^{-2}$, thus $Y'=-2y'y^{-3}$, then (E) is equivalent to:
$$-2x^3Y'-3\frac{x^4}{Y^2}=1. $$

I am stack... Please, can anyone help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Just a Hint**

Put $y^2=z$

the equation becomes

$$2x^3z'-z^2-3x^4=0.$$

observe that $z_0=x^2$ is a solution.

thus if $w=z-z_0$ then
$$2x^3(z'-z'_0)=(z-z_0)(z+z_0)=(z-z_0)(z-z_0+2z_0)$$

$$\implies 2x^3w'=w(w+2z_0)$$

Yes, you can finish after a partial fraction decomposition.

then
$$y=\sqrt{w+x^2}$$

Comment: Sorry, I don't see a link between equation $2x^3w'=w(w+2z_0)$ and $2x^3z'-z^2-3x^4=0$.
 equation $2x^3w'=w(w+2z_0)$ is equivalent to $2x^3z'=z^2-x^4$.

Comment: Yeh, i know it. But i don't understand the link between your first equation and your last equation

Comment: Thank you Abd-Allah for your help but i don't know how you add $z_0$ on your first equation : $$ 2x^3z'-z^2-3x^4.$$ Thanks, i will try to solve it by your hint :)

Answer (score 1):

Starting as Abdallah Hammam in his answer, let $y^2=z$ $$4x^3yy'-3x^4-y^4=0\implies 2x^3z'-z^2-3x^4=0$$ Now $z=x^2+u$ leads to $$2 x^3 u'-2 x^2 u-u^2=0$$ Now $u=\frac 1 v$ leads to $$2 x^2 \left(x v'+v\right)+1=0$$ that is to say $$xv'+v=-\frac 1 {2x^2}$$ The homogeneous equation is easy to solve $$x v'+x=0\implies v=\frac{c}  x$$ Variation of parameters $$xv'+v=-\frac 1 {2x^2}\implies c'=-\frac 1 {2x^2}\implies c=\frac 1 {2x}+C\implies v=\frac 1 {2x^2}+\frac C x$$ Now, $u=\frac 1 v$, $z=x^2+u$ and $y=\pm \sqrt z$ would lead to the solutions.